# Unable to get the web content using LWP::Simple but able to get content from LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl

I am trying to run below code to parse the contents of html page for the below URL

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
$response = get("http://www.viki.com/");
print $response;
```

Nothing gets printed. This is working if emulated from a browser.

Comment: I'm sure there is a question in here somewhere, just having trouble seeing what it is?

Comment: unable to retrieve the content of the page. Is there a way we can get it without using user agent

Answer (score 3):

When I try to access `http://www.viki.com` using `LWP::UserAgent` I get the following response:

```
<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

The `get` subroutine in `LWP::Simple` is implemented as follows (at least in version 6.13).

```
sub get ($)
{
    my $response = $ua->get(shift);
    return $response->decoded_content if $response->is_success;
    return undef;
}
```

As you can see, the `get` method will only return the content if the response is a success, otherwise it will return `undef`.

The response from `LWP::UserAgent` is a 403 error, in other words not a success.  Therefore, `LWP::Simple` will return `undef` for the same URL.

It appears that the website (`http://www.viki.com`) is checking the user agent string and only returning content to "valid" user agents.  `LWP::Simple` is hard-coded to use `LWP::Simple/$VERSION` as the user agent.

If you really must use `LWP::Simple` then you could force the user agent like this:

```
use LWP::Simple qw/ get $ua /;

$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0');

print get('http://www.viki.com');
```

`LWP::Simple` exposes the `LWP::UserAgent` instance that it uses internally as the optionally included `$ua` variable.  It is still necessary to configure the user agent on this instance to get this particular page to load.

Comment: It worked for me if an user agent is mentioned in my script

`$url = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$url->timeout(300);
$url->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0');`

I want to know how can we do this using LWP::Simple

Comment: The page you are requesting returns a 403 error.  LWP::Simple only returns content if the page load is successful, a return code between 200 and 299.

Comment: I have updated the answer again as LWP::Simple makes the internally used LWP::UserAgent instance available as an optionally included variable.